# DynamoDB - The provided key element does not match the schema

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to delete a user's reservation at a specific date and time but I encountered this error and am not sure how to resolve it. Any advice will be appreciated.

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    let body;
    let response;

    switch (event.routeKey) {

        case 'DELETE /bookings/{user_name}/{restaurant_name}/{time}/{date}':
            //have to specify date and time because user might make reservation on same date,same restaurant, at 2 different timings
            var params = {
                TableName: 'hearty_eats_bookings',
                Key: {
                    'user_name': event.pathParameters.user_name,
                    'restaurant_name': event.pathParameters.restaurant_name,
                    'time': event.pathParameters.time,
                    'date': event.pathParameters.date
                },
            };

            dynamo.delete(params, function(err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                return callback(null, { "message": "booking cancelled" });
            });
            break;


        default:
            throw new Error("Unsupported route: " + event.routeKey);

    }
}
```

Event JSON
[image]
Error Message
[image]
Event JSON
[image]
DynamoDB Details
[image]
[image]

Comment: your DynamoDB has the wrong schema, currently each user can only have a single booking and you can only delete that single booking based on the username. You was want to use the date or booking_id as the sort key. Generally you should read up on how DynamoDB works.

Comment: @luk2302 do you have any recommendations on what to put as the partition key. I'm not too sure what to put instead of user_name.

Comment: @codelala - here is a video from AWS which explains their single-table design principle. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KYy8X8t4MB8 it will give you few ideas about how you can use the dynamodb tables the way AWS does. It also explains partition keys. Overall the partition should allow you to access some type of data together across multiple lines - this is not a very good description, but let you watch the video.

Comment: Typically, an API would contain `{date}/{time}` rather than `{time}/{date}`.

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB's `DeleteItem` API only takes the keys of the item as a parameter, however you have included much more than the keys in your request:

```
  Key: {
       'user_name': event.pathParameters.user_name,
       'restaurant_name': event.pathParameters.restaurant_name,
       'time': event.pathParameters.time,
       'date': event.pathParameters.date
  },
```

If you need to manage an item at the time and data level, then you should include that as part of your key, for example:

| PK | SK | Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| User123 | GreatChinese#2022-12-10T18:00:000Z | Table for 2 |
| User789 | GreatIndian#2022-12-09T19:00:000Z | Table for 4 |

```
  Key: {
       'PK': event.pathParameters.user_name,
       'SK': `${event.pathParameters.restaurant_name}#${event.pathParameters.date}`
  },
```

If you wish to continue with your current approach then use the following as `Key`

```
  Key: {
       'user_name': event.pathParameters.user_name
  },
```

In summary, you must only specify the tables partition key and sort key in the `Keys` parameter of the DeleteItem request.

Comment: Thank you so much, I now have a better idea on how to modify my dynamodb :)